# OS X rootkit/spyware scanners?

Tags: macos, spyware, rootkit, anti-spyware

For OS X, I have discovered Rootkit Hunter recently and liked the functionality.  What other rootkit/spyware scanners for OS X have been developed that are available for use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems you've found the top dog when it comes to rootkits. For spyware, [MacScan](http://macscan.securemac.com/) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect [ClamXAV](http://www.clamxav.com/) may handle spyware and rootkits too.  Or there's the port of [chkrootkit](http://chkrootkit.darwinports.com/)